# How to remove zero-width space characters &zwj; from the text

Tags: ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-4

I have text which contains the `&zwj;` [Zero width joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Zero_width_joiner) which is not visible in UI, But when I send it as an SMS, it shows as `?` question mark in iPhone.

I have tried removing it by using gsub but its not getting removed.

```
text.gsub("&zwj\;", "")
```

Is there any way to remove such invisible character from the text?

---

**Update:**

In addition to @matt's answer

Unicode has the following zero-width characters:

- U+200B zero width space
- U+200C zero width non-joiner Unicode code point
- U+200D zero width joiner Unicode code point
- U+FEFF zero width no-break space Unicode code point

To replace them in a text, you can use a simple regex:

```
text = text.gsub(/[\u200B-\u200D\uFEFF]/, '')
```

Comment: What's the \ for? just use `"&zwj;"`.

Comment: @Phlip `\` is use to escaping special characters. Removing `\` also will not work.

Comment: Run `p text`, or `puts text.inspect`, and edit your post and add the results. There might be more funny business, such as a zero-width joiner character, inside the &zwj;!

Comment: Your string does not contain any special characters. Please edit and use copy/paste to insert the string containing the special character.

Comment: @Phlip The \ is used to escape the `;` to ensure the regex engine matches the semicolon literally (in case semicolon is a special control character)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The string `&zwj;` is the HTML character entity for the zero-width joiner. When a web browser sees it it will replace it with an actual zero-width joiner, but as far as Ruby is concerned it is just a 5 character string.

What you want to do is to specify the *actual* zero-width joiner character. It has the codepoint U+200D, so you can use it like this, using Ruby’s Unicode escape:

```
text.gsub("\u200D", "")
```

This should remove the zero-width joiner characters, rather than looking for the string `&zwj;` which your original code was doing.

Answer (score 2):

```
"blah blah blah".gsub(/[^[:print:]]/, '')
```

Should remove all non-printable characters.

Comment: Thanks for checking @Kris But this removes the line breaks as well.

Comment: "\u200B" (zero width space) matches /[[:print:]]/

Comment: Indeed "\u200B" is a problem. `gsub(/[^[:print:]]/, '')` does not remove it. I stayed with `.gsub(/[^[:print:]]/, '').gsub("\u200B", '')` until I find a better solution